# add fields to ERC721 tokens, still belongs to the standard?

Tags: contract-design, tokens, erc-721, nft

if starting from the code of an erc721 token, I add fields beside the name, symbol and URI, is it still a token that respects the standard?

Add in the contract, not in the JSON file.

The most general question is actually: what is the standard?

I added a field to this [code](https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/tree/a2ae3f0d71de2a36d042c676a1766ea416afa3a4/src/contracts/tokens), declaring the setters and adding it to the interface, it works, now I still have an erc721 token or not?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the question. It will be helpful if you can paste the resulting code here that you are using so that the next person may see it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't modify the functions, events and member variables of the standard, you are good to go.

Comment: If I don't change the default functions (transfer, approval, etc.), but add new ones?
What do you mean by Members?

Comment: Yes, you can add new functions. The standard defines the function it *does* have, it doesn't define the functions it *can't* have.